# How i prevent to dispose error characters from database?

Tags: html, mysql

I´m spanish and we use for example the letter "ñ" and some accent marks. I'm having this problem where I have a database in PhpMyAdmin where there are some data the includes the "ñ" and accent marks. When I use that information on the screen it shows an error character with a question mark. What can i do to prevent that? Not using the letters and accent marks is not an option.

This is an example of what I see: https://ibb.co/NjkRf9D (Not possible to upload the image with IMGur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your database is not configured as Unicode

Try this :

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database_name charset=utf8;
ALTER TABLE your_table_name charset=utf8;
```

and read  [this article on handling Unicode](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) also

[Official documentation on Charset](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link! But it's not working. It keeps showing the error characters. I have tried the solution that gives the second link and either

Comment: Thanks! It worked just using ```mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');``` after open the conection.